# MongoDB How to update documents with repeat value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user documents like

```
[{uid:2,name:"Micheal",count:0},{uid:3,name:"Rubby",count:0}]
```

Now I have a `uids` array `[2,2,2,3,3]` , If the `uid` of document is in `uids` , the `count` will `+1`, now I use

```
db.getCollection('users').update({ uid: { $in: [2,2,2,3,3] }},{ $inc:{count:1}})
```

The Question is :

I found the the value of `count` only add one time with `uid 2`  , It should add three times, both `uid3`  How to resolve it?

Comment: Update only update the first document it found, to update multiple document you need to add option `{ multi: true }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the the value of count only add one time with uid 2 , It
>   should add three times,

That is not how `mongoDB` processes its update queries. The number by which a field is to be incremented by, is determined by the value provided to the `$inc` operator and nothing else.

The `mongoDB` query selector is clever enough to select a record only once, even if it has matched the *same query condition* more than once.

You would have to do a bit more than just firing an update query, in the client side:

- Maintain a `count` map, which basically stores, the `number` by which the `count` for a given `uid` needs to be incremented by. It is determined by how many times the `uid` has occurred in the `uidArr` array.
- Filter all unique `uid`, which you would be using in your `update` query later.

sample code:

```
var updateCountMap = {};
var uidArr = [2,2,2,3,3];
var filteredUniqueIdArr = [];
uidArr.forEach(function(i){
  if(updateCountMap.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    updateCountMap[i]++;
  }
  else{
    updateCountMap[i] = 1;
    filteredUniqueIdArr.push(i);
  }
})
```

- Then use the [`bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update) API to update the entries for all the unique `uid`, by the number of occurrance of the `uid` in the `uidArray`.

sample code:

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('users').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
filteredUniqueIdArr.forEach(function(j){
  bulk.find({"uid":j}).update({$inc:{"count":updateCountMap[j]}},
                                    {"multi":true});
})
bulk.execute();
```

Test data:

```
db.users.insert([{"uid":2,"count":0},{"uid":3,"count":0}])
```

Test Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fc583460ebfe7758f4fd5"), "uid" : 2, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fc583460ebfe7758f4fd6"), "uid" : 3, "count" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [`multi`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) to `true` because:

> By default, the [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method updates a single document. Set the Multi Parameter to update all documents that match the query criteria.

```js
db.getCollection('users').update(
    { 'uid': { $in: [ 2, 3 ] } },
    { $inc: { 'count': 1 }}, 
    { 'multi': true }
)
```

If you want to update the field based on elements occurrence in the `uids` array you will need to do little more work.

```js
// Function to define sort order.
function compare(a, b) {
    return a < b ? -1 : ( a === b ? 0 : 1);
}

// Function to count occurrences of `uid` in the array.
function counter(arr) {
    arr.sort(compare); // optional
    var counts = {};
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        var n = arr[index];
        counts[n] = n in counts ? counts[n]+1 : 1;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Demo:

```js
> var uids = [ 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 ];
> var myCounter = counter(uids);
> myCounter 
{ '2': 3, '3': 2 }
```

You can then use ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/) operations to update your documents.

```js
var bulkOp = db.users.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

db.users.find( { 'uid': { '$in': uids } ).forEach(function(doc) {
    var value = doc.uid;
    bulkOp.find( { 'uid': doc.uid } ).updateOne( {
        '$inc': { 'count': myCounter[value] }
    } );
} );

bulkOp.execute();
```